# Show/Hide content if a Checkbox is checked in JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am new in JSP and java. I want to execute a piece of code that will show or hide content if a check box is pressed. I was thinking of it like this: if the checkbox is pressed, a boolean variable will become true. If the boolean variable is true, then execute another if statment.

But in my final result, all my content is hidden. Can someone can explain to me why this happens, or give me another way to do it?

```
<%boolean  hide = false;
    String strCheckBoxValue= (String) session.getAttribute("checkweekends");
        if (strCheckBoxValue != null) {
            hide = true;
        } %>
        <c:if test="${hide == true}">

     <c:if test="${a.dateFormat_hideweekends(day+z) !=''}">


     <c:if test="${a.getData(time,day+z, sala)!=''}">
    <TD align="center" valign="middle" width="100" title="${a.getData(time,day+z, sala)}" style="color:#00008B;text-overflow: ellipsis;width: 200px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;" bgcolor="#FFFF00">
    <c:out value="${a.getData(time,day+z, sala)}"  />
    </TD>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${a.getData(time,day+z, sala)==''}">
    <TD align="center" valign="middle" width="100"  bgcolor="#90EE90">
    </TD>
    </c:if>
    </c:if>
    </c:if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what this code does. Your `Java` code is executed on the *server side*. When a user clicks a check box, the code that is ran is ran on the *client side*.

You can't make your Java code work on the *client side* because it's a *server side* language. This is a job for a client side language like Javascript. For example..

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="eventHook()"/>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function eventHook() {
        // This code is ran when the checkbox is changed.
    }
</script>
```